# how to change the canvas background color dynamically android application?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am very new to android applications,
 I am able to change the background color directly as follow

```
        // Clear canvas to white
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
        **paint.Color = Color.White**;
        canvas.DrawPaint(paint)
```

But I want to change it dynamically
 I have Three Buttons on my layout:

- ( 1. Red ( @+id/btnRed ),
- 2. Black(@+id/btnBlack) and
- 3.White( @+id/btnWhite ) )

I want to change the background color of the canvas on click of the buttons ?
can any body help me on this with some sample code.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio is the application you use to author your code. The `[visual-studio]` tag is only intended for questions about Visual Studio, not about code.

Comment: stackoverflow is _not_ a free code-writing service. You may start your research [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/). And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?products=xamarin&term=Xamarin.Android) you can find a lot of samples.

Comment: ok, Thanks and sorry for wrong tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

I create a `CustomView` Add a method called `ChangeColor`. After set color, you should call `this.Invalidate();` to re-draw control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace CanvasDemo
{
   public class CustomView: View
    {
        Paint mDstPaint;
        Bitmap mDstBitmap;
        Canvas mDstCanvas;

        public CustomView(Context context,Color color): base(context)
        {
            mDstPaint = new Paint();
            mDstPaint.Color=Color.Blue;
            SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, null);
            mDstBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(150, 150, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            mDstCanvas = new Canvas(mDstBitmap);


        }

        public void ChangeColor(Color color) {
            mDstCanvas.DrawColor(color);
           this.Invalidate();
        }
        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);

            mDstCanvas.DrawRect(50, 50, 150, 150, mDstPaint);
            canvas.DrawBitmap(mDstBitmap, 0, 0, mDstPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Change it color by `Button`

```
   public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        CustomView custom;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            Button BlackButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BlackButton);
            Button RedButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.RedButton);
            Button WhiteButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.WhiteButton);
            LinearLayout view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
            BlackButton.Click += BlackButton_Click;
            RedButton.Click += RedButton_Click;
            custom = new CustomView(this,Color.White);
            WhiteButton.Click += WhiteButton_Click;
            custom.SetMinimumHeight(500);
            custom.SetMinimumWidth(500);
            //re-view control  
            custom.Invalidate();
            view.AddView(custom);
          // ]
        }

        private void WhiteButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //   throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            custom.ChangeColor(Color.White);
        }

        private void RedButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            custom.ChangeColor(Color.Red);
        }

        private void BlackButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            custom.ChangeColor(Color.Black);
        }
```

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the left upper corner), it will help others who have similar issue.